# Bootstrap - Change the color of visited links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I would like that all the links change their color when they are visited. I am working with Bootstrap and this is what I have tried so far (that doesn't work properly) :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="unicode">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">
               a{
                 color:#d99a30 !important;
                 &:hover{ color:#37404e !important;}
                 &:visited{ color:#37404e !important;}
               }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                  <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3><a href="some_link.html">Link</a></h3>
                       </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the syntax for LESS/SASS instead of plain CSS. Here is an example of your code using CSS.

```
a { color:#d99a30 !important; }
a:hover { color:#37404e !important; }
a:visited { color:#37404e !important; }
```

If you want `:hover` and `:visited` to be the same, you can also simplify that rule too:

```
a { color:#d99a30 !important; }
a:hover, a:visited { color:#37404e !important; }
```

Comment: This will work. Chances are you can remove the `!important;` as well.

Comment: I would recommend that too @TedGoas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom css for your all hyperlink. You should use `!important`  with your custom css otherwise this css is not work.

```css
a {
    color: blue !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: blue !important;
}
a:hover {
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Sschools Home</a><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">W3Schools HTML Tutorial</a><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/">W3Schools CSS Tutorial</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The :visited selector style links to pages you have already visited.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'css' that you wrote is actually 'Sass' and will only work if you compile it.
To change the color replace the `&` with `a` and moving everything with `&` outside the brackets like so:

```
a{
   color:#d99a30 !important;
}

a:hover, a:visited{
   color:#37404e !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this no need to use !important

```css
body a {
    color: #d99a30;
}
body a:hover{
   color:red;
  }

body a:visited{
    color:black;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="unicode">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                  <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3><a href="some_link.html">Link</a></h3>
                       </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:link, a:visited {
     color:#FFFFFF;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2DC2E8;
}
```

The above code worked for me... as I wanted a link that was 'visited' to appear as if it didn't with a hover.

Thanks !